# 'Conceptual' proof of Holder's inequality or Minkowski's inequality

Tags: analysis, intuition

Holder's inequality and Minkowski's inequality are two basic inequalities about $L^p$ spaces, stating that $||fg||_1 \leq ||f||_p||g||_q$ when $p, q$ are conjugate, and that $||f+g||_p \leq ||f||_p + ||g||_p.$

Holder's inequality is closely related to the fact that $L^p, L^q$ are each others' duals for $p, q$ conjugate (and $1 < p, q < \infty$). However, the only proofs I know of these inequalities are very 'algebra heavy' and I find it hard to think of what the 'ideas' of the proofs are, or how to compress them in my head beyond (for Holder) 'do funky algebra and apply Young's inequality' and (for Minkowski) 'do funky algebra and apply Holder's.'

Is there some more intuitive/conceptual proof of either inequality? Say, some abstract way of seeing the dual of $L^p$ is $L^q$ in a way that allows you to deduce Holder, or some other proof that doesn't use any 'clever' algebraic manipulations (or, perhaps, any motivations for these clever manipulations?).

Comment: You can use Jenesen's inequality to prove Holder;s inequality.